# Is it possible to open a TAR file without a header and metadata?

Tags: linux, tar, metadata

I am trying to open a TAR file without a header containing the file information and other metadata. I know for certain this is a TAR file. Running `xxd` and `head` on the tar gives me the following:

```
00000000: 686a 7f25 7b65 6c0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b  hj.%{el.........
00000010: 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b  ................
00000020: 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b  ................
00000030: 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b  ................
00000040: 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b  ................
00000050: 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b 0b0b  ................
00000060: 0b0b 0b0b 3b3b 3b3b 3d3f 3f0b 3b3b 3b3b  ....;;;;=??.;;;;
00000070: 3b3b 3b0b 3b3b 3b3b 3b3b 3b0b 3b3b 3b3b  ;;;.;;;;;;;.;;;;
00000080: 3b3d 3f38 3c39 3e0b 3a3f 3f3a 3a38 383c  ;=?8<9>.:??::88<
00000090: 383e 390b 3b3a 3a3b 3e3e 0b2b 3b0b 0b0b  8>9.;::;>>.+;...
```

Is there any way to open this file even without the header information?

Comment: Try a tool that is versatile, such as 7-Zip, which can be installed as a Linux application (as p7zip, which is *not* kept updated) or as the Windows version which runs in wine. It might, or might not, be able to handle that tar file.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It didn't work in my case, stating that it cannot read the TAR, but thank you for the idea.

Comment: Another utilty to try: "rar" as in winrar, I find it to be more useful than 7zip.